# getting KeyError when trying to determine row number for a particular date of datetime64 dtype using pandas df

Tags: pandas, datetime64, getlocation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13MyG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGCtm.png)

`df_wead = df_weather_d['settlement_day']

df_loc = pd.DataFrame(df_wead)

df_loc.index.get_loc('2024-02-25')`

get following error -  KeyError: '2024-02-25' and not sure why

Comment: You don't have a `'2024-02-25'` key in your index. Given your images it looks like you have a range index (0, 1, 2…)

Comment: Please include text as text, not screenshots.